# why is the mongodb collection find not working?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am trying to search a mongodb using pymongo as `collection.find({},{"project": "IO80211"})` but the search doesnt seem to work
it seems to list all the rows in that collection,any guidance on why the search is not working?

```
try:
    print("Trying to create tags...")
    dbuser = os.environ.get('muser', 'techauto1')
    dbpass = os.environ.get('mpwd', 'techpass')
    uri = 'mongodb://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@techtechbot.scv.company.com:27017/techautomation'.format(**locals())
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    db = client.techautomation
    collection = db['static_radars']
    print ("going to for find..")
    #cursor = collection.find({"project:%s"%project})
    print(collection)
    cursor = collection.find({},{"project": "IO80211"})
    print ("going to forloop")
    for document in cursor:
        print('%s'%document)
except (pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect, e):
    print('Warning %s'%e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the query,

the second one is the projection,

as it says [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

So you can remove the first empty parameter and pass the query instead

```
cursor = collection.find({"project": "IO80211"})
```